# QT C++ - Signals and Slots: "No such slot QLabel..." even the SLOT function is existing in my class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

So I am trying to learn Qt Framework with C++. I am in the middle of understanding signals and slots but I am having a hard time creating a customized slot. So as I follow some tutorials, my program ended up with the following error:

> QObject::connect: No such slot QLabel::updateMessage() in main.cpp:28

Where **updateMessage()** is declared as a **public slot** inside my **Test** class

The following are some snippets from my code:

**Test.h**

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(void);
    ~Test(void);
    void setMessage(char *tMsg);
    char* getMessage();

    QWidget *window;
    QGridLayout *layout;
    QLabel *lblMsg;
    QPushButton *btnShow;


public slots:
    void updateMessage();

private:
    char msg[80];
    QString str;

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test t;
    t.window->setWindowTitle("Testing Qt");
    t.window->setLayout(t.layout);
    t.window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

Test::Test(void)
{
    window = new QWidget;
    lblMsg = new QLabel;
    btnShow = new QPushButton("Show message");

    connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),lblMsg,SLOT(updateMessage()));
    layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(lblMsg);
    layout->addWidget(btnShow);

    char str1[] = "Hello, Qt World!";
    setMessage(str1);
}


Test::~Test(void)
{

}

void Test::setMessage(char *tMsg)
{
    memcpy(msg, tMsg, sizeof(msg));
}

char* Test::getMessage()
{
    return msg;
}

void Test::updateMessage()
{
    string strMsg(getMessage());
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(strMsg);
    lblMsg->setText(qstr);
    delete msg;
}
```

**HelloQtWorld.pro**

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Tue Nov 15 00:30:22 2016
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = HelloQtWorld
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += stdafx.h Test.h
SOURCES += anotherClass.cpp \
           main.cpp \
           stdafx.cpp \
           GeneratedFiles/qrc_helloqtworld.cpp
RESOURCES += helloqtworld.qrc
```

Can also someone try to explain for me how Signals and Slots work? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),lblMsg,SLOT(updateMessage()));
```

You are connecting with slot of `QLabel` instead of slot of your class.

This should be changed to

```
connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(updateMessage()));
```

Pay attention at new Qt 5 syntax for signals and slots.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. It is now working. Also thank you for sharing some references about signals and slots. I appreciate it. Thankk youuu. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `label` of type `QLabel` does not have a slot named `updateMessage()`.
Your class `Test` has.

Change the connect to:

```
connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(updateMessage()));
```

This will connect the button's `clicked` signal to your `Test` object`s`updateMessage` slot.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for helping me. So now I understand why it is not working. The 3rd parameter should be the class where the slot is declared/located, right? THANK YOUUUU! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your slot is declared at `Test` class, not `QLabel` class, but you are trying to connect to the slot as if it was declared at the `QLabel`:

```
connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),lblMsg,SLOT(updateMessage()));
```

You should connecto to `this`, instead of `lblMsg`:

```
connect(btnShow,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(updateMessage()));
```

Comment: Hello. Now I understand why it is not working. Thank you so much for the help. :)